# ICBIT API using Python

Tags: python, socket.io

I am trying to use the ICBIT API from Python.

https://icbit.se/api

The ICBIT API is implemented using `socket.io` but I don't have any experience using it.

Does anybody have any sample on how to connect to a server using `socket.io` and send/receive requests using Python?

Thanks in advance,

Jordi

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) from python to make request to **ICBIT API**.